# Solspace Calendar Event Editing

Tags: craft3, events, solspace, plugin-solspacecalendar, editing

I'm using Solspace Calendar for Craft and I'm currently trying to implement the edit event form. Once a user selects an event on the calendar they are taken to the event page. On this page I have the edit event form.

The fields in this form will be added to the event entry once submitted. The issue I'm having is getting the form to submit.

```
<form method="post">
                    {{ csrfInput() }}
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="calendar/events/save-event" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="{{ (siteUrl~"availability/event/{id}")|hash }}" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="eventId" value="{{ event.id }}" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="slug" value="{{ event.slug }}" />
```

Looking at the demo documentation, the two fields I'm not too sure about is the 'action' and 'redirect' fields. I have changed the redirect field to match the current event page. But I don't know what needs to go into the 'action' field.

Currently as you can see, it's 'calendar/events/save-event'. Is this a demo template I have missed. Does this need to be changed to something more specific. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to make sure you include all of the Calendar field inputs in order for this to work. If you're trying to hide them for your workflow, you can set the fields to hidden, or wrap them in a `div` and hide them with CSS. :)

Comment: Does a user have to be logged in to actually to see the page containing the event edit form? A problem I didn't realise until recently is that logged out, I get a 'Page not Found error'. But the page is fine when I'm logged in